# Refer to created object that is assigned to a variable in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a question regarding classes in Python. When I create a new object like this and add it to a variable:

```
user = User.objects.create(name='The Name')
```

Can I use that variable to refer to that newly created object? Like this:

```
print(user.name)
```

Comment: What else would the point of variables be? Also, why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Rawing I guess, but I thought it was only possible when I retrieved with the function `get()` in Django. Maybe a dumb question...

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create), which clearly shows that the newly created object is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Actually, it's the only way to use newly generated object - if you, for instance, did this:

```
User.objects.create(name='The Name')
```

you couldn't access that same object ever again. After that, if you do this:

```
print(User.objects.create(name='The Name'))
```

you will create another new object and print its name. So, you basically use variable to store that object you have created.

Comment: `Model.objects.create()` already saves the object to the database.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer. But also, I was thinking if he make further changes to object after creation, that will not be saved of course.